# Make link to foreign key object in admin screen

Tags: python, django, admin

I have class like this which has the `ForeignKey`

```
class MyLog(SafeDeleteModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

then I set `user` in the list_display of MyLog in admin page.

```
class MyLogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["id","user"]
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["id","username"]
```

Now I want to make link in user of MyLogAdmin page to UserAdmin,

Is it possible?

I think some framework(such as php symfony) administrator system does this automatically.

However is it possible to do this by django admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, strangely enough, not a builtin feature. But we can effectively do this ourselves with:

```
from django.utils.html import format_html


class MyLogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'username_link']

    @admin.display(ordering='user__username', description='User')
    def username_link(self, obj):
        return format_html(
            '<a href="{}">{}</a>',
            reverse(
                'admin:appname_customuser_change',
                kwargs={'object_id': obj.user_id},
            ),
            obj.user,
        )
```

with the *`appname`* the name of the app where you defined the `CustomUser` model (which is *not* per se the same as the `MyLog` model).

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: We can boost efficiency by fetching the details of related models in the same query in a `ModelAdmin` with the [**`.list_select_related`** attribute <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_select_related). In this specific case this thus looks like:
>
> ```
> class MyLogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>     list_select_related = ['user']
>     # …
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much !! I changed `'<a href="{}"></a>'`, to `'<a href="{}">{}</a>'`,